# MySQL counting in assocative tables with reference to third table

Tags: php, mysql

How can I count rows based on a association with a third row?
In the example below I get the same result for both counts which is not the amount of "cwt_packages " nor the "cwt_products " table.

Find below the query I wrote

```
SELECT *, COUNT(p1.pkg_id) pkg_count, COUNT(p2.prd_id) prd_count FROM cwt_companies  
LEFT JOIN cwt_packages p1 ON p1.pkg_ins_cmp = ic_id
LEFT JOIN cwt_products p2 ON p2.prd_pkg = p1.pkg_id AND p1.pkg_ins_cmp = ic_id
```

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand your question correctly. You what to count the number of products in each packages?

Comment: Yes i want to count the amount of packages and products for each company!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to write a query, without knowing the structure of the tables, but something like this shoud work:

```
select *, count( pkg1.pkg_id ) as pkg_count,
    ( select count( prd.prd_id ) as prd_count
        from cwt_companies c2
            left join cwt_packages pkg2 on pkg2.pkg_ins_cmp = c2.ic_id
                left join cwt_products prd on prd.prd_pkg = pkg2.pkg_id
        where c1.ic_id = c2.ic_id ) as prd_count
from cwt_companies c1
    left join cwt_packages pkg1 on pkg1.pkg_ins_cmp = c1.ic_id
group by c1.ic_id;
```